# WebSQL and other databases not working with HTML5 apps

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, database, ubuntu-sdk, html5

I am trying to develop an app for Ubuntu Touch using HTML5 and I need to create a database to store, well, everything in it. But QtWebKit supports neither WebSQL nor IndexedDB.
Is there any workaround to make the app support databases without anything beyond JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

QtWebkit supports WebSQL and IndexedDB: The following code samples return true:

```
var websqlAvailable = typeof window.openDatabase != 'undefined';
var indexeddbAvailable = typeof window.indexedDB  != 'undefined';
```

As a side notice, only an older version of indexeddb is available in QtWebkit.

More information on using Web SQL, IndexedDB and Web Storage in Ubuntu Touch can be found here: http://daniel-beck.org/ubuntu-html5-platform-storage/